# INSERT INTO by using WITH

Tags: sql, db2, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I've created a table called infotext in dB2 to be used in order to output values generated when debugging some artifact.

I the table info text I have 2 columns called datastamp of type timestamp and info of type varchar(250).

The problem I'm facing it is related with the error:

> An unexpected token ")" was found following "rom SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1".  Expected tokens may include:  ")".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601

When running a statement as mentioned next:

```
INSERT INTO INFOTEXT  (DATESTAMP, INFO) 
            with datas as (select current timestamp from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1),
              other AS (
                select current timestamp from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);
```

What is causing my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the last of your query you need to put a select clause as after the with statement you need a select referring that CTE.

```
INSERT INTO INFOTEXT  (DATESTAMP, INFO) 
        with datas as (select current timestamp from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1),
          other AS (select current timestamp from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
        --just a guess
        select * from datas
        union all
        select * from other;
```